# Can this trigonometric equation be reduced to a simpler form?

Tags: trigonometry

We have the right triangles depicted in the following png:

[image: Triangles]

Obviously, the relation $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ can be expressed as $\frac{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$, but I got the sense that this can be reduced to an expression that depends only on a and b. Intuitively, I'm thinking that if we look at each triangle in isolation, then for instance $x_2$ cannot be expressed in terms of $b$ alone. But if we look at both triangles, since $c$ is invariant, there should be some relationship between $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ and $a, b$. Any ideas?

Comment: Try substituting $c=0$, $c=1$ and $c>>a$, and find that the ratio $x_1/x_2$ does depend on $c$.

Comment: Since $x_1^2 -a^2 = x_2^2 -b^2$ I am not sure you could get the relation as you want.